# Clearing tkinter canvas containing label

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I create such a code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

def b(canvas):
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.update()
    print "works"

def main(): 
    root = Tk()
    canvas=Canvas(root)
    canvas.config(width=400, height=300)
    bb=Button(canvas, text="ssss",command=lambda:b(canvas))
    bb.place(x=100,y=200)
    root.geometry('400x300')
    aa=Label(canvas,text="aaaaa")
    aa.place(x=10,y=200)           

    canvas.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the problem is that after clicking on a button label is not destroyed despite the fact that a function with `canvas.destroy("all")` runs.

Answer (score 1):

The label is not deleted when `canvas.delete("all")` is invoked because you have used place to display the label, so it is not an item of the canvas. To make the label a canvas item, you need to replace

```
aa.place(x=10,y=200)
```

by

```
canvas.create_window(10, 200, window=aa)
```

And then `canvas.delete("all")` will also delete the label.